# PHP Error: SimpleXMLElement::__construct()

Tags: php, xml, rss

For some reason the script I use to get the feedburner count as a string to use around my site (http://ios-blog.co.uk) has stopped working :( This is the error that it throws out:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 2:     parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 1 and HEAD in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY> in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 6: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: HEAD line 1 and HTML in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: </BODY></HTML> in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 7: parser error : Premature end of data in tag HTML line 1 in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: in /home/connect.php on line 83

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/connect.php on line 83

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/connect.php:83 Stack trace: #0 /home/connect.php(83): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<HTML><HEAD><me...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/connect.php on line 83
```

This is the PHP that i am Using:

```
//get cool feedburner count
$whaturl="http://api.feedburner.com/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=iosdevblog";

//Initialize the Curl session
$ch = curl_init();

//Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whaturl);

//Execute the fetch
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Close the connection
curl_close($ch);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$fb = $xml->feed->entry['circulation'];
echo $fb;
//end get cool feedburner count
```

The file is large - where it says line `83` it relates to: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);`

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah... the feedburner is now deprecated - thats why it suddenly stopped :( https://developers.google.com/feedburner/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here on this line

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: 301 Moved in /home/connect.php on line 83

It's giving HTTP code 301 moved.

If you visit this link

https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=iosdevblog

It's actually 404ing, there is no XML there.